# stop booting ubuntu 20.04 on a raspberry pi 4 from SSD after upgrade

Tags: boot, usb, raspberrypi

I have an ubuntu desktop 20.04.2 64bit on raspberry pi 4
I have booted a lot of time without sd card on usb ssd.
the kernel vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi is my last boot.
when I update to vmlinuz-5.4.0-1029-raspi, the utility that I use to decompress kernel failed.

So I mount the ssd on other pc and manual decompress it, but not work.
I watch in /boot and /boot/firmware and do not find the same configuration:
config.txt have a new structure. Before update config.txt liked user.txt now no more etc.

cmdline.txt was booting by LABEL but the new is all different.

I have a backup of /boot
Have I to restore all /boot file and don't care of the exinsting file on /boot ???

Anyone have the same disaster?

best regards,
Leonardo

### UPDATE

The @HappyTux answer is right.
I have do a mistake:
In my decompress kernel script I use extract-vmlinux, previous I use zcat -qf

extract-vmlinux can fail without exit code <> 0 and it does.

```bsh
# check_vmlinux
...
    readelf -h $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || return 1

    cat $1
    exit 0
...
```

this function bit is call by:

```bsh
...
# Finally check for uncompressed images or objects:
check_vmlinux $img

# Bail out:
echo "$me: Cannot find vmlinux." >&2
```

and the `rerurn 1` is not used.

so I mount my usb ssd on other pc and decompress it by zcat.

My error is not remember that /boot/firmware is a mount point of bootable partition:
I use this path to decompress /boot/firmware but, on my support pc,
boot partition is **not** mounted
so my change is hide at boot time on rpi.

I have to decompress kermel using boot partition and restore the right config.txt too. This make **sub ssd boot again**.

I do not know why /boot/firmware without boot partition mounted is not empty!  This help me to make my mistake.

Now on new Ubuntu 20.04.2 is no more needed kernel decompression:
on config.txt you can use
`kernel=vmlinuz`
directily without decompress it.

best regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Did you update the OS/packages through apt since it last booted OK? I'm in a similar position, Raspberry Pi 4b, Ubuntu Server on a USB drive, not booting since doing an `apt upgrade`. Mine hangs up on `Begin; Running /scripts/local-premount` for over a minute before dropping me to a BusyBox prompt after a handful of `mdadm: No devices listed in conf file were found` messages. (disclaimer: not hijacking the thread, just wondering if it might be down to a package update that's changed something even though my updates were only Python and Docker related).

Comment: I wiped my install and then found it's because there must've been a kernel update in a recent apt update which reset something we will have done in the original set up.

Basically, we have to decompress the vmlinuz file again as that has changed and the Pi can't decompress it at boot time or something.

You'd have to mount the usb drive on another computer and run the following command in the system-boot directory: `dd if=vmlinuz | zcat > vmlinux` and that will do the decompression for you.

I recreated the issue straight away on my fresh install too and this step fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need it to restore you old /boot and you are back to what you had before. That is how these machines boot with all the files contained in it, it is your entire boot configuration. They look for certain named files by the firmware to load into memory then continue on to the next needed... until finally it loads the kernel which line contains the partitionID or label to load the / and you are booted.

You can probably just edit the files on the new /boot to get it going again, the text files that controls the booting. On my `Buster` install they are `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` and `/boot/firmware/config.txt`. The first telling it the partition to load the second the kernel and intramfs.